# Sortable ListView with Drag n Drop and buttons, how to know list.position on button press

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, draggable

I have a Sortable ListView from this code:

https://github.com/pnavk/Drag-and-Drop-ListView

On each row i have a button, i need to know the list.position every time i click on the button.
Before implementing the drag n drop listview i was getting the position in this way:

In my ListViewAdapter i use this code:

```
            if (!editImageButton.HasOnClickListeners)
            {
                editImageButton.Click += delegate
                {
                    ((MainActivity)context).ShowEditPhaseDialog(position);
                };
            }
```

and in my activity:

```
        public void ShowEditPhaseDialog(int phasePos)
        {
            var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            userInput = new EditText(this);
            userInput.Text = data[phasePos].PhaseName;
            builder.SetTitle("Phase Edit");
            builder.SetMessage("Edit or Delete a phase");
            builder.SetPositiveButton("Save edit", (s, ex) => { EditPhase(userInput.Text, phasePos); });
            builder.SetView(userInput);
            builder.SetCancelable(false);
            builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (s, ex) => { HideKeyboard(userInput); });
            builder.SetNeutralButton("Delete", (s, ex) => { RemovePhase(phasePos); });

            dialog = builder.Create();
            dialog.Show();
            ShowKeyboard(userInput);
        }
```

But now after implementing the draggable adapter, every time i change the position of the row, the onbutton clicklistener remain the same with the old position. how i can solve this problem?

DraggableListAdapter has this function for swapping items:

```
        public void SwapItems(int indexOne, int indexTwo)
        {
            var oldValue = Items[indexOne];
            Items[indexOne] = Items[indexTwo];
            Items[indexTwo] = oldValue;
            mMobileCellPosition = indexTwo;
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using **button.Tag** to store the position and send the position in this way:

```
        if (!editImageButton.HasOnClickListeners)
        {
            editImageButton.Click += delegate
            {
                ((MainActivity)context).ShowEditPhaseDialog(Int32.Parse(editImageButton.Tag.ToString()));
            };
        }
```